# excel VB regexp 5.5 capturing group

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a problem using regexp in excel macro, by calling regex.execute(string), instead of getting an array of returned capturing groups, I always get single return which is the whole string specified in the pattern.
By using the same pattern in http://www.regexr.com/, I can see the return nicely grouped. What am I missing from this:

```
Private Sub ParseFileName(strInput As String)
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplace

    'Sample string \\Work_DIR\FTP\Results\RevA\FTP_01_01_06_Results\4F\ACC2X2R33371_SASSSD_run1
    strPattern = "FTP_(\w+)_Results\\(\w+)\\([\d,\D]+)_(SAS|SATA)(HDD|SSD)_run(\d)"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set strReplace = regEx.Execute(strInput)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = strReplace.Count
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
    End If
End sub
```

In the end, `strReplace.Count` always shows 1, which is the whole string FTP_01_01_06_Results\4F\ACC2X8R133371_SASSSD_run1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.SubMatches` to get capturing groups values:

```
Private Sub ParseFileName(strInput As String)
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplace As MatchCollection
    Dim i As Long

    'Sample string \\Work_DIR\FTP\Results\RevA\FTP_01_01_06_Results\4F\ACC2X2R33371_SASSSD_run1
    strPattern = "FTP_(\w+)_Results\\(\w+)\\([\d,\D]+)_(SAS|SATA)(HDD|SSD)_run(\d)"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set strReplace = regEx.Execute(strInput)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = strReplace.Count
        For i = 0 To 5
            ActiveCell.Offset(i + 1, 1) = strReplace(0).SubMatches(i)
        Next
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "(Not matched)"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Thanks a lot! Sorry, cannot upvote